# does mule server 3.4.2 get automatically restart in any chance?

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-el, mule-cluster

Does mule server 3.4.2  get automatically restart in any chance?

In my production server mule server restarted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In a rare scenario, small network disturbance will create this auto restart. if you look at wrapper.conf, there is a setting called jvm ping timeout. If wrapper didn't receive jvm ping in defined time(30 secs in general) wrapper will think jvm is unresponsive and will restart. check your logs at restart time and see whether there is any information on jvm unresponsiveness before restart.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in live environment where Server (Mule runtime platform) auto restart and when i checked the logs i have found below error message -

```
Pinging the JVM took NN seconds to respond
```

Where NN is the second.

This could cause when there is a memory/thread leak at server layer which is causing jvm to be busy and unable to ping the JVM.

If this is not the case then you can resolve this issue by changing the below attribute value under $MULE_HOME/conf/wrapper.con

```
wrapper.ping.timeout=30
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Could you check whether the server has enough memory allocated? Check the logs at points where the server restarted for clues.

Also, verify how the server is started, is there a windows service/script starting the server?

HTH.

Comment: we are not using any script to restart the mule server. we could not find any clues in the logs. is there any other options to check

Comment: Not really, the tanuki wrapper may restart the Mule JVM if it becomes unresponsive, that is why I suggested allocating more memory. It is difficult to resolve this if you are unable to replicate the issue. I recommend creating a new Mule + deployment and monitor whether the issue persists.